# smarty and suphp permissions - saving as different user 

Tags: php, apache, permissions, suphp

Right now i have to give 777 permission to the directory where files are saved and instead of saving it as "user1" is saving it as apache

`-rwxrwxrwx  1 apache apache  6865 Aug 30 17:20 homepage.tpl.php`

How can the files be saved as user1 and without 777 permission outside my docroot wich is home/user1/public_html/

lets say in /home/user1/private/homepage.tpl.php

Im using a Centos LAMP with suPHP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved**

To fix it I had to reinstall suphp with this conf.

/etc/suphp.conf

`check_vhost_docroot=true`

and use the correct handlers

```
[handlers]
;Handler for php-scripts
x-httpd-php="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi"

;Handler for CGI-scripts
x-suphp-cgi="execute:!self"
```

Inside the virtual host

```
suPHP_Engine on
suPHP_UserGroup user user
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .php3 .php4 .php5
suPHP_AddHandler x-httpd-php
```

Comment: doh! You answered yourself? That's odd and I don't think your get any +1 for that!

Comment: but I believe you should have edited your own post, added [SOLVED] and voila :)